# SKSpritenodes child nodes don't show up in self

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, child-nodes

Under my class scene I have:

```
let health = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "healthBar")
```

And when the dog damages the enemy I want the enemy to spawn a health bar above it showing its current health.

The code below works fine if I change the enemy.addChild(health) line to self.addChild(health). But when it is enemy.addChild(health) the health bar is completely invisible. I know for a fact the health bar is there because I can print enemy.children and it show its there but its not visible. Any suggestions?

**Note I can't just use self.addChild(health) because I need multiple health bars that follow multiple enemies positions. Thats why I need each enemy to have its own child health bar.

```
if body1.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategories.DodgingDogPlayer && body2.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategories.Enemy{ //if the player has hit an enemy
    if dogAttacking == true{
        dogAttackAnimation.position = CGPoint(x: dodgingDogPlayer.position.x, y: dodgingDogPlayer.position.y + 80)
        dogAttackAnimating()
        let waitToFade = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.5)
        let fadeOutSequence = SKAction.sequence([waitToFade, fadeOut])

        dogAttackAnimation.run(fadeOutSequence)
        if body2.node?.name == "Orange Cat" || body2.node?.name == "Brown Cat" || body2.node?.name == "Black Cat"{

            if ( body2.node?.childNode(withName: "health") != nil) {

                print ("already has health")
                if let enemy = contact.bodyB.node as? Enemy{

                    health.xScale = CGFloat(fixedHealthBarLength * CGFloat(enemy.healthStat))
                    health.position = CGPoint(x: enemy.position.x, y: enemy.position.y + 50)
                    health.texture?.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.nearest

                    enemy.healthStat -= 1
                    if enemy.healthStat <= 0{
                        body2.node?.removeFromParent()
                    }
                }

            } else if ( body2.node?.childNode(withName: "health") == nil) {

                print ("doesnt have health")
                health.yScale = 2
                health.zPosition = 10
                health.name = "health"
                if let enemy = contact.bodyB.node as? Enemy{

                    health.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
                    health.xScale = CGFloat(fixedHealthBarLength * CGFloat(enemy.healthStat))
                    health.position = CGPoint(x: enemy.position.x, y: enemy.position.y + 50)
                    health.alpha = 1
                    health.texture?.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.nearest
                    enemy.addChild(health)

                    enemy.healthStat -= 1
                    if enemy.healthStat <= 0{
                        body2.node?.removeFromParent()
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the position of the child node? it could be that either the zPosition is less then the enemys (so the enemy is hiding the bar) or that the position is too low (so the enemy is also hiding the bar). My suggestion would be to adjust the zPosition of the health bar.

Comment: It would help to know what you've already tried.  As E. Huckabee said, try changing zPosition.  You need to also see if you can get it to appear under any circumstances, by, say, commenting out your lines affecting the health node.  You might also consider that the xScale is dependent on the health stat, so if that were zero, the xScale would be zero and it would not render.

Breakpoints, or even just print statements, might help you narrow down where the problem is.  From the info you've given, it could be a number of places.